# Qt Opengl VBO data corrupted

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vbo

I have been trying for almost two weeks by now to get VBOs working in a Qt environment, but so far nothing has worked. My goal is to create a grid of triangles to use as the base of some terrain, like in the Lighthouse3D tutorials. The relevant parts of my program are as follows:

GameWindow.h

```
class GameWindow : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GameWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GameWindow();

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() override;
    virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height) override;
    virtual void paintGL() override;

    QGLShaderProgram *shaderProgram;

private:
    int frame;

    std::vector<GLfloat> grid;

    QOpenGLBuffer vbo;
    GLuint vboId;

    QVector3D position;
};
```

GameWindow.cpp

```
GameWindow::GameWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent),
    position(QVector3D(0, 5, -5)),
    vbo(QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer))
{}

GameWindow::~GameWindow()
{}

void GameWindow::initializeGL()
{
    QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL();
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    shaderProgram = new QGLShaderProgram(QGLContext::currentContext());

    QGLShader vertex(QGLShader::Vertex);
    vertex.compileSourceFile(QDir(":/shaders").absoluteFilePath("basic.vert"));
    shaderProgram->addShader(&vertex);

    QGLShader fragment(QGLShader::Fragment);
    fragment.compileSourceFile(QDir(":/shaders").absoluteFilePath("basic.frag"));
    shaderProgram->addShader(&fragment);

    shaderProgram->link();

    QImage image;
    image.load("C:\\test.png");

    int width = image.width(); //=10
    int height = image.height(); //=10

    for (int i = 0; i < height-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width-1; j++) {
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i));

            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i+1));

            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j+1));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i+1));


            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j+1));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i+1));

            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j+1));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i));

            grid.push_back(GLfloat(j));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(0.0f));
            grid.push_back(GLfloat(i));
        }
    }

    vbo.create();
    vbo.bind();
    vbo.allocate(grid.size()*sizeof(GLfloat));

    vbo.write(0, grid.data(), grid.size()*sizeof(GLfloat));
    vbo.release();

    /*
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, grid.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), grid.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //*/

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) << std::endl;
}

void GameWindow::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    QOpenGLWidget::resizeGL(width, height);
}

void GameWindow::paintGL()
{
    shaderProgram->bind();

    QMatrix4x4 projection;
    projection.perspective(45, qreal(width())/qreal(height() > 0 ? height() : 1), 0.1f, 100.0f);

    QMatrix4x4 view;
    view.lookAt(position, QVector3D(0, 0, 0), QVector3D(0, 1, 0));

    QMatrix4x4 model;
    model.translate(-0.5f, 0, 0);

    QMatrix4x4 mvp;
    mvp = projection * view * model;

    shaderProgram->setUniformValue("matrix", mvp);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    vbo.bind();

    shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer("vertex", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vbo.size());

    shaderProgram->disableAttributeArray("vertex");

    /*
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, grid.size());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    */

    shaderProgram->release();

    update();
}
```

Shaders

```
//Vertex Shader
attribute vec3 vertex;
uniform mat4 matrix;

varying vec3 pos;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vertex, 1);

    pos = vertex;
}

//Fragment Shader
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor.rgb = pos;
}
```

And finally I open the window like this:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(3, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setSamples(4);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

GameWindow *w = new GameWindow();
w->show();
```

After running this program, I get something similar to this, though it often changes:
[image: Weird Result]

As you can see from the code, I have tried using both `QOpenGLBuffer` and raw `gl*` commands create and draw my VBO, with similar results. Nothing from Google has been helpful, so now I turn to you for help. What is wrong with my VBOs, why is the data corrupted?

## Note:

When I run I get this error in stdout:

```
[opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 565] OpenGL Error: 1286
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Unsupported framebuffer format.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Unsupported framebuffer format.
[opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 720] OpenGL Error: 1280
```

But I dont know if that has anything to do with it.

## Note 2:

Trying to use `vbo.read()` crashes my program.

Comment: Could you please explain why you downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you issue this command:

```
shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer("vertex", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
```

you are indeed saying that for each 3 floats it is to be interpreted as 1 attribute. So, to draw, you need to call:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, grid.size()/3);
```

Note. It seems to me that vbo.size() gives you the amount of bytes into the vbo object, not the amount of elements into the buffer

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it :D

Answer (score 0):

In Qt OpenGL operations are only valid if placed inside a `makeCurrent` … `doneCurrent` block or within the `…GL` methods. With neither precondition fulfilled there's no OpenGL active upon which VBOs could created.

Solution: Move your OpenGL initialization code from the constructor into `initializeGL`.

Comment: Oh wow, it turned out to be so simple :/ The strange thing is it worked correctly for a single triangle... But thank you I'll try this out :)